# Rails: change localhost:3000 to https://

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, ruby-on-rails-4, https

I'm in development and using the `html5 geolocation` on my `rails 5` app:

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setGeoCookie);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function setGeoCookie(position) {
    var cookie_val = position.coords.latitude + "|" + position.coords.longitude;
    document.cookie = "lat_lng=" + escape(cookie_val);
}
```

it's working fine with `firefox` and all browsers except for `safari`. With `safari` the `allow pop up` doesn't appear.

I did some research and found..... that safari (unlike Chrome and Firefox) does not allow access to geolocation over the HTTP protocol - only HTTPS. Even for localhost.

The solution is to either use another browser in development or serve Rails over HTTPS.

Can someone give me pointers on how to serve Rails over HTTPS in development?

Comment: It appears to me that simply using another browser is the easiest option.

Comment: Yes I agree @Sergio Tulentsev! The only question is, will it work with safari when I deploy it?? Since I cant test it right now!

Comment: It depends on your operating system and setup. Especially what rails server you are using. Basically you have to create a self signed certificate (PEM) and trust it in the OS. https://gist.github.com/tadast/9932075

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way to serve Rails over https will be to use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). It just provides a secure tunnel to localhost. Extremely easy to use

Comment: This is rather slow though, and it seems they also throttle request rates. For a page in the development env with no caching, most requests get blocked. A solution like this might work out better for some: https://rossta.net/blog/local-ssl-for-rails-5.html

Answer (score 1):

Even though it has been 5 years since this question was asked I feel that I need to make my input for anyone who is will stumble upon this question in the future.
I had similar issue with Rails 6 and making a call to the external API, which allowed only https connections. So after some research I discovered that the easiest solution is to modify the `puma.rb` file and create two directories `config/certs` & `config/certs/.keep` and update the gitignore.
The following has to be added to the `puma.rb` file:

```
if Rails.env.development?
  unless File.exist?(Rails.root.join('config', 'certs', 'localhost.key'))
    def generate_root_cert(root_key)
      root_ca = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new
      root_ca.version = 2 # cf. RFC 5280 - to make it a "v3" certificate
      root_ca.serial = 0x0
      root_ca.subject = OpenSSL::X509::Name.parse "/C=BE/O=A1/OU=A/CN=localhost"
      root_ca.issuer = root_ca.subject # root CA's are "self-signed"
      root_ca.public_key = root_key.public_key
      root_ca.not_before = Time.now
      root_ca.not_after = root_ca.not_before + 2 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 # 2 years validity
      root_ca.sign(root_key, OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new)
      root_ca
    end

    root_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(2048)
    file = File.new( Rails.root.join('config', 'certs', 'localhost.key'), "wb")
    file.write(root_key)
    file.close

    root_cert = generate_root_cert(root_key)

    file = File.new( Rails.root.join('config','certs', 'localhost.cert'), "wb")
    file.write(root_cert)
    file.close
  end

  ssl_bind '0.0.0.0', '8443', {
      key: Rails.root.join('config','certs', 'localhost.key'),
      cert: Rails.root.join('config','certs', 'localhost.cert')
  }
end
```

I have also created a [gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/msuliq/1aa809b9450f1020ce87e49023e8ae55) too. I would appreciate if you star the gist so you can easily find the most up to date version of it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use cloudflared https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflared, it's free and doesn't have any of the limitations ngrok has like having to change the domain every so often.

Answer (score -4):

You can make your Rails app to run on HTTPS by adding the below line in `application.rb`

```
 config.force_ssl = true
```

Or as Nwocha suggested you can as well use ngrok.